# Twilio Conference vs Call

Tags: twilio

In Twilio, when creating an outbound `Call` we don't have ability to add third person later. But we can do it when using a `Conference`. Calls are a bit cheaper than conferences. So it looks strange, why should anyone bother with creating outbound `Call`s and not start `Conference` directly?

To summarize: is there any advantage of using `Call` vs `Conference` for "regular" (two person) outbound calls? Besides small cost factor.

Comment: It clearly says `No contracts or upfront costs. Pricing does not include per-minute Voice pricing.`, which means your conference will have additional voice charges as well. Link: https://www.twilio.com/voice/conference

Comment: @TarunLalwani: I'm aware of this, and it's mentioned in question

Comment: My bad I miss interpreted it

Answer (score 0):

For two person is not difference, the difference through the documentation is for big groups of call members. The difference between both is to keep latency down that is the main difference with other services.

**Conference**
Allows for audio conference calls with up to 250 participants. The calls are automatically hosted in the closest of the six geographic regions `Twilio` currently offers to keep latency down.

For calls with more than 250 participants `Twilio’s` new “Epic Conference” service can now handle an unlimited number of participants.

But, I concrete: 
is there any advantage of using Call vs Conference for "regular" (two person) outbound calls? **No, is'nt any advantage.**, the main feature is for big groups.

Comment: Why are you so certain? From your answer follows, that Calls are just "restricted" Conferences. Why would anyone do such a thing?

Comment: I'm already used both it @dimakura and I know you said "Besides small cost factor." but, for this case, the implementation to keep a group segmented in different endpoints for conference has different cost, giving users a "premium sensation". Why they do that? I don't know.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing new in your answer.